# Autofilling state and city based on zip code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I am new to web development and I ran into an issue with a registration form that I'm building for our business. I am using this guide: http://css-tricks.com/using-ziptastic/. This is my first experience with AJAX and JSON and I just can't get the city and state to autofill as soon as I'm done typing in the zip code. Any solutions/suggestions/alternatives will be much appreciated. I set up a basic jsfiddle to test everything out: http://jsfiddle.net/7VtHc/

HTML:

```
<p>Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip" /></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" id="city" /></p>
<p>State: <input type="text" id="state" /></p>
```

jQuery, etc.

```
$("#zip").keyup(function() {
var el = $(this);

if ((el.val().length == 5) && (is_int(el.val()))) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: "zip=" + el.val(),
    success: function(result, success)

    $("#city").val(result.city);
    $("#state").val(result.state);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting your success function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/7VtHc/5/
I will added that `===` in JavaScript will check that type are the same. [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).
There is no need to create an `is_int()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#zip").keyup(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: "zip=" + el.val(),
                success: function(result, success) {
                    $("#city").val(result.city);
                    $("#state").val(result.state);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

*P.S. When you create a JSFiddle make sure you include jQuery from the menu on the right.*

Comment: This helped me too. Remember to empty the city and state if you decide to backup and add a different zip. I put it right inside the keyup: `$("#zip").keyup(function () {                    $("#city").val(null);                        $("#state").val(null)`

Comment: The trouble with ZipTastic is it will only come up with one city per zip code. There are other factors to consider, also. I can't display all the code here ... it's complicated. But I will list some things to consider if correct data is really important. 1) You should return every city/state available for a zip and put it in a dropdown. 2) Also allow a city/state lookup so if user changes the city or state after results to something that is incorrect, an error will be produced.

Answer (score 4):

For India you can use pincode API for free, You can get the city with other information as JSON format.

Example: https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/641001

Usage: `https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${Your-pincode}`

If any cors Policy occured means use this :

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${Your-Pincode}`

Example:

```
{
  "Name": "Coimbatore",
  "Description": null,
  "BranchType": "Head Post Office",
  "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
  "Circle": "Tamilnadu",
  "District": "Coimbatore",
  "Division": "Coimbatore",
  "Region": "Coimbatore",
  "Block": "Coimbatore South",
  "State": "Tamil Nadu",
  "Country": "India",
  "Pincode": "641001"
}
```

I am using this in `Angular-8`
Thanks.